# When scrolling, navigation falls behind content

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

on my [site](http://www.bradlyspicer.net/) whenever I scroll down and the navigation is stretched out it falls behind the content.

Here is my script:

```
.menu {
position: relative;
z-index:9999;
}

.post {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
font-size: 16px;
}



<script>
    var num = $('.header').height(); 

    $(window).bind('scroll', function () { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) { 
    $('.menu').addClass('fixed-nav'); 
    $('.wrapper').before($('.menu')); 
    } 
    else { 
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed-nav'); 
    $('.menu-menu-container').prepend($('.menu')); 
    } 
    });
    </script>
```

I have tried adding `z-index` to as high as I can, but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I added a `z-index: 999;` to your #header css rule and it worked atleast on chrome.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of adding it there. Thanks

Comment: @BradlySpicer you should accept this as answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: You should not force someone ,let him think

Comment: @Bradly Spicer Glad to help, you would get there eventually.

Comment: Why is it, when I scroll down it shrinks in size? even when I add a min-height of 100px?

Comment: what is shrinking exactly?

Comment: @Wilmer the scrolling navigation bar: http://puu.sh/7q1Um.png  it shrinks it's height and hides everything.

Also in Firefox it's still sitting behind .post

Comment: yes apparently if you remove the filter property in header it works in firefox.